# Issues importing models from AutoCAD

Tags: import

Often, I download 3D models provided by furniture companies or manufacturers to make sure they're the correct scale and all for our interior renders. They usually have 3D dwg files as an option, but I almost always need to clean it up some in Blender before I can use it as they usually aren't optimized for rendering. The problem there is, I'm very limited on what file formats both AutoCAD and Blender will work with. The only two options I seem to have are DXF and STL, but I always have trouble getting them to work properly. The DXF files only import bits and pieces at random, if anything at all, and trying to convert it to an STL is hit-or-miss because the models aren't always watertight. I use Chief Architect for all of my architectural modeling, which can import 3D DWG files directly, but it triangulates everything so sometimes the geometry is broken or missing.

Is there a good standard practice for this that I'm missing? Or is there a specific DXF format I should be using? Blender asks for v0.9.6, but I'm not sure what the equivalent is for that in AutoCAD and Google has been no help. I'm not even sure what kind of 3D data the model is by default, because most of the time it tells me the models can't be converted to a mesh, solid or surface. I can link one of the manufacturers with files I have to fight with, in case you need to see it for specifics. I'm working in AutoCAD 2022, and have access to both Blender 1.92 and 1.93

I'm also, unfortunately, working on a company computer where they severely limit what we can install. I've seen some of the third-party DWG-to-DXF converters out there, but I can't install them here. I could install one on my home computer, but moving the files back and forth would be a hassle and I can't remote in to my home computer, so I'd have to convert them on my lunch breaks or after work. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks in advance! [Here](https://www.hon.com/design-symbols) is that link

Comment: I'm wondering, what's your workflow currently ? What I would do, in Autocad > Save as DXF (Mine suggests R12, that's what I went for). Then in Blender, import the dxf. Select everything > edit mode > Tris to quads. result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zPN4.png

Comment: @Gorgious Ideally, that's what I want it to be. I try those steps, but for some reason when I import to Blender nothing actually opens. I just tried the R12 format. I actually got something to show up, but it's not the entire model and it's all curves.

Comment: Bumping this just in case anyone else can help, since it's an issue I'm still having. I've tried all versions of DXF that AutoCAD can export at this point, the only one that always gets results is the R12/LT2 format. But it's usually just curves with a ridiculous amount of vertices (the last I tried had 3.5 million vertices), and no geometry.